# React Redux Dispatch Action inside Const

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have the below component that displays the pageName from Redux store.

```
const content = ({ pageName }) => {
    return (
        <div className="content">
            {pageName}
        </div>
    );
}

  const mapDispatchToProps = {
    DataStatement,
  }

const mapStateToProps = state => ({ pageName : state.Page.Name })


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) (content);
```

Within same above component, I need to reset data in the redux. I have this reducer

```
 case 'DATA_STATEMENT':
    return {
      ...state,
      Data : {
        ...state.Data,
        StatementData : action.StatementData,
      }
    }
```

and this action

```
export const DataStatement = (StatementData) => ({ type: "DATA_STATEMENT", StatementData: StatementData  });
```

So all I need to do inside Content.js is `DataStatement('');` so I empty out the value inside DataStatement. I added `DataStatement('');` to right before return inside content, it doesn't work. How can I reset DataStatement in Redux store.

Comment: Your code looks fine. Where are you calling this.props.DataStatement?

Comment: `const content = ({ pageName }) => { HEREE
    return (`

Comment: Before return statement inside content.. Am I supposed to call it elsewhere? To be honest, I don't know where to call it...

Comment: That's it I supposed! In functional components use the hook `useEffect`. See how [https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send an action before rendering then you can do like this

```
const content = ({ pageName, beforeRendering }) =>
{
    beforeRendering();
    return (...);
}
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    beforeRendering: dispatch(DataStatement()),
})
```

but be careful because if you are using any data from state which is affected by the reset then it may cause a loop.